# Regular expression to replace digits after first 4 digits

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I am trying to write a Regular Expression that replaces all the digits of a number with *'s after first 4 digits.

For example

```
var number = 123456789
```

it should be replaced with `1234*****`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Javascript:

```
var maskedNumber = String(number).substr(0,4) + Array(String(number).length - 3).join('*');
```

In PHP:

```
$maskedNumber = str_pad(substr($number, 0, 4), strlen($number), "*");
```

Answer (score 3):

In PHP:

```
function replaceDigit_callback($matches) {
    return $matches[1] . str_repeat('*', strlen($matches[2]));
}
$text = '1234567890';
echo $text, "\n";
$text = preg_replace_callback('#(\d{4})(\d+)#', 'replaceDigit_callback', $text);
echo $text, "\n";
```

Output:

```
1234567890
1234******
```

In JS:

```
var number = 1234567890;
var output = number.toString().replace(/(\d{4})(\d*)/, function (str, p1, p2) { return p1 + p2.replace(/./g, '*') });
```

Comment: Isn't this a far too complex solution? See my approach with `str_pad`

Comment: @akirk, depends. If $text contains only number and nothing else, then yes, this is indeed too complex solution. +1 for `str_pad()` version ;)

Answer (score 0):

You Can set your PHP coding..I provide you logic....

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class RegexSubstitution
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string testString1 = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8";
      Regex testRegex1 = new Regex( @"\d" );

      Console.WriteLine( "Original string: " + testString1 );
      Console.WriteLine( "Replace first 3 digits by \"digit\": " + testRegex1.Replace( testString1, "digit", 3 ) );
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the logic matches with what he needs... `123456789` should be replaced with `1234*****` rather than `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` with `*, *, *, 4, 5`.

Answer (score 0):

Without regex:

```
var number = '123456789';
var output = '';

output = number.substr(0,4);
for ( var i = 0; i < number.length - 4; ++i )
{
    output += '*';
}
```

Input `number` has to be string !

Conversion

```
var number = 1234567890;
```

to string looks just like:

```
var number = 1234567890 + '';
```

or

```
var number = parseString(1234567890);
```

Comment: If number is already stored in variable, conversion can be done with `toString()`, i.e., `n.toString()`. If it's not stored (`12345.toString()`), it won't work, bug who use hard-coded numbers nowadays?